# Content being overshadowed on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

For some reason when I hover over menu links on my site, half of the content (image slider) below disappears.

I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening

URL: http://swampfighter.bmdigitalgroup.com/

Thanks so much!

Comment: remove `height: 100%;` from  the css rules under `.navbar ul li:hover > a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are setting the height to 100% on the hover state for the list item. If you remove that it should behave correctly.

If you want it to cover the whole height of the navigation bar, I would set my hover styling to this:

```
.navbar ul li:hover > a {    
    position: relative;
    height: 90px;
    background: #7eb378;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```